# Simulating a poker win rate over time

Tags: plotting, simulation, stochastic-calculus

Poker players start with a fixed bankroll (`bankroll`) and play with a win-rate `winRate` (say measured in dollars per hour) and standard deviation of win-rate (`sd`).

How can I use the Wolfram Language to graph/simulate a poker player starting with `bankroll` and playing for, say, 100 hours (`t = 100`)?

If the total winnings ever dip below `bankroll`, the simulation result should just be `$0` since the player has no ability to keep playing anymore!

Comment: Look at `RandomProcess`, using `WienerProcess`. That should get you started.

Comment: You may want to incorporate the [Kelly criterion](http://www.herrold.com/brokerage/kelly.pdf) , which maximizes the expected value of the logarithm of wealth (the expectation value of a function is given by the sum, over all possible outcomes, of the probability of each particular outcome multiplied by the value of the function in the event of that outcome).

Comment: Applying the Kelly bet sizing methodology (a proportional bet, sized relative to bankroll, risk, and signal noise at each sequence of play) protects a player from their bankroll ever going to 0.

Comment: what about buyins?

Answer (score 2):

```
ListPlot[
 NestList[# RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1.05, .1]] &, 100, 50],
 Joined -> True,
 AxesLabel -> {"Games played", "return (dollars)"}]
```

[image]

Or...

```
ListPlot[
 Table[
 NestList[# RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1.05, .1]] &, 100, 50], 
 10],
 Joined -> True, 
 AxesLabel -> {"Games played", "return (dollars)"}]
```

[image]

The bankroll constraint is easily incorporated:

```
ListPlot[
 NestList[
  If[# > 60, # RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1.05, .1]], 0] &, 100,
   50],
 Joined -> True,
 AxesLabel -> {"Games played", "return (dollars)"}]
```

Here the "bankroll constraint" is 60 (even though you start with 100).  If your game ends if you ever go beneath your starting money, you will often stop fairly quickly.

Comment: What has this to do with the poker, or the bankroll constraint?